# signtool.exe not found c# and cannot publish because project failed to build

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, clickonce, signtool

I have programed one c# windows application and i am trying to run that on my clients(customer's) machine.

First>>>I tried to publish that application.
Whie publshing it is giving me two errors
1.cannot publish because project failed to build
2.signingtool.exe not found.

Event though searching on web , i did not get appropriate solution for this problem.
Then i tried to make exe of the application by releasing the application in x86 mode.

When i double clicks on application file(exe)...it gets opened and gives me error
1.microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine

After this error i installed the setup for AccessDatabaseEngine. 
Although installing this...it gives me error...

what should i do for these errors???
Help me out for both the problems of same case...

i have refered this post
[ClickOnce - Cannot publish because a project failed to build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7869129/clickonce-cannot-publish-because-a-project-failed-to-build)

and tried to build and publish the project via menus on the top....but still the problem is same...

Comment: error is just signingtool.exe not found...

Comment: its because error is comming on my client's(customer's) machine which is not present over here...i think you have understood what i want to say...plz help

Comment: Well you never told us this was happing on a client's machine, not yours. Please edit your your question and include **ALL** of the details and we can help. We are not sitting next to you, if you do not tell us, we don't know. For example, how are you calling `signtool.exe`? from inside your program itself or as a "After Build" event? What arguments are you passing to signtool.exe?

Comment: o...but now u understood...can u help me out...

Comment: No I don't understand. That's what I am trying to tell you. You have not provided enough details to help someone else understand what is causing the problem. Please answer my 3 questions from my previous comment.

Comment: when i simply run the program...it is running....but when i publish it...it gives me two errors 1. signingtool.exe not found ...2. can not publish failed to build...

Comment: Two errors? That is the first we heard of that, This is what I am talking about. Start over, re-write your question and pretend you are explain the steps you are doing as if you are talking to someone who has never programed before.

Comment: sir now i have edited...plz help me out...

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12434264/62576) may help. The poster seems to be trying an end-around to the previous question by posting under a different account.

Comment: You have not given any new info (but you can now delete your old comments) How are you "Publishing on your clients comptuer" Are you running visual studio on their machine, or is this happening when you ship them a completed EXE? You need to provide **NEW INFORMATION**. Delete all of the text in the post and **write a step by step guide** of what you do **when it works**, then write another list of what you do **when it does not work**.

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry, I had this problem.
It's quite an easy process:

1. Open Programs and Features
2. Select Microsoft Visual Studio
3. Click Change
4. Select Modify if prompted (depends on your VS version)
5. Choose ClickOnce publishing tools and install them

Also, I found a bunch of cool stuff that you can install from there.