# Visual Studio ClickOnce deployment gives error when trying to publish a C# WPF app

Tags: c#, visual-studio, deployment, ftp, clickonce

I can build/rebuild the project in VS without an error and provides me the below screen.

[image]

But when I'm trying to deploy it using a clickOnce it gives me below errors.

- Cannot publish because a project failed to build.
- An established connection was aborted by the software in your host
  machine.
- Couldn't connect remote machine.
  As below.

[image]

To make sure about the ftp server i logged using given credentials and ensure with FilZilla and ftp credentials working fine.
This failure happen recently, and i was deploying to the same FTP from 2021.

So my question is.
Is this happen due to project error or FTP permission error ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ClickOnce - Cannot publish because a project failed to build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7869129/clickonce-cannot-publish-because-a-project-failed-to-build)

Comment: @AbhishekDutt Thank you, I have already checked and followed it(revert changes in SVN, Delete bin files and .suo) but no luck. 
Also i didn't change date, but i only generated a new clickOnce manifests(signing) due to previous one was expire.

Comment: @AbhishekDutt But i as a one of answer in that question says to build project using 
 VS > Build > Build Solution gives me below result (It doesn't build my solution) 
Build: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped